# Is the ordering of the digits matters or not in while forming the number this problem?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we need to find all possible $16$ digit numbers ($0$ can be on the left most place ) having digits $0,1,2,3,4$ with $0$ digit being used $4$ times, $1$ digit being used $5$ times, $2$ digit being used $2$ times and $3$ digit being used $3$ times and $4$ digit being used $2$ times

> My method was to first choose $2$ out of $16$ for digit $4$, after that we choose $3$ out of $14$ for digit $3$ and next we choose $2$ out of $11$ for digit $2$ , ,$5$ out of $9$ for $1$ digit and left $4$ for $0$ . In all I used choosing and then multiply all of them but that's not the actual answer, can someone tell what's going wrong as such order matters here right on what we are choosing from first then second ... ?

Comment: Please write an *INFORMATIVE* title... one that deals with the content of your question.

Comment: Sorry for that edited it

Comment: Do you see why your title is still extremely vague?  Order ***of what***?  "This problem"???  Topology?  Complex analytic sheaf cohomology?  Algebraic number theory?  Also "How to decide it?" could apply to almost *any* problem. 
 Please try again.  (Look at other postings to see the style.)

Comment: Your method is sound.  There are $\binom{16}{2}\binom{14}{3}\binom{11}{2}\binom{9}{5}\binom{4}{4}$ such sequences.

Comment: Thanks but i think problem is that answer is a lower number than this , am i doing overcounting or something ?

Comment: As a general rule, whenever you run into doubts on such problems, it is wise to try out what (if anything !) is wrong on a much smaller problem of the same type.

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer Give the supposed answer and maybe people can help you. Maybe leading zero is prohibited or something like this.

Comment: It is specifically mentioned that "$0$ can be at the leftmost place" @IvanKaznacheyeu. You could recalculate using a less error prone formula, $\frac{16!}{4!5!2!3!2!}$

Comment: Alright sure @trueblueanil thanks . By the way can you just mention how we see whether here the order matters or not ?

Comment: By $16!$ in the numerator, uou can easily see that order matters because  we have *permuted* all the items, the factorials in the denominator correct for items that appear multiple times

Comment: To continue, while $16!$ shows that order matters, the denominator shows that order within each group of similar numbers does not matter, So hopefully you are now clear over the issue,

Comment: Thanks yes indeed , mine mistake i realized was with the confusion of the C formula itself i forgot that it takes count without order ones  .